# Group by wether or not the cell exists in another table as well

Tags: mysql

My SQL syntax is MariaDB (MySQL)

I have a table with organisation spokepersons, and a table with VIP organizations, and a table with presentations. How do I group or sort by wether the spokeperson's organisation is VIP, so that VIP organisation spokepersons show up on top when retrieving all presentations?

Table presentations: `int presentation_id, int person_id, varchar title, date date`

Table persons: `int person_id, varchar name, varchar function, varchar organisation`

Table VIP_orgs: `int org_id, varchar org_name`

Query that doesn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
    person_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(64),
    organisation VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
);

INSERT INTO `persons` (name, organisation) VALUES
    ("Guy Fieri",       "VIP-org"),
    ("Fiona",           "VIP inc."),
    ("Mr. Robot",       "Evil Corp"),
    ("Marcus Antonius", "Rome"),
    ("Cicero",          "Rome"),
    ("Shrek",           "VIP inc.");
    
CREATE TABLE presentations (
    presentation_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    person_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (presentation_id)
);

INSERT INTO `presentations` (person_id) VALUES
    (1),(1),(1),(1), -- guy fieri has 4
    (2),
    (3),(3),(3),(3),(3),
    (4),(4),(4),(4),
    (5),(5),(5),
    (6),(6),(6),(6);

CREATE TABLE VIP_orgs (
    org_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    org_name VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (org_id)
);

INSERT INTO `VIP_orgs` (org_name) VALUES 
    ("VIP-org"),
    ("VIP inc.");

SELECT organisation, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM `presentations`
JOIN `persons` ON `presentations`.person_id = `persons`.person_id
GROUP BY (SELECT org_name FROM `VIP_orgs` WHERE `VIP_orgs`.org_name = organisation), organisation
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

What I expect it to do:

return a table `org_name, (total combined number of presentations by each spokeperson of that org)`

Sorted by count of presentations, grouped by organisation, VIP organisations grouped on top.
The VIP and non-VIP parts should be sorted by count independently. The returned table *should* thus look something like this:

```
name      count
VIP inc.  5
VIP-org   4
Rome      7
Evil Corp 5
```

The query works 50%: it counts all presentations and sorts it, but it doesn't seem to group by VIP organizations. In actuality the returned table looks like this:

```
name      count
Rome      7
VIP inc.  5
Evil Corp 5
VIP-org   4
```

Comment: @Strawberry working on it, sorry

Comment: @Strawberry fixed, thanks for raising my attention on it.

Comment: Given your sample data this is not possible since you don't have a ralationship between presentations and persons or persons and vip_orgs - please fix your sample data and table definitions.

Comment: @P.Salmon the relation is implicit. There's a table with vip orgs, more an array, and there's a table with persons, who each have a varchar organisation they belong to. The relation between persons and presentations is `person_id`

Answer (score 1):

The schema doesn't look right. I would suggest creating an `organisations` table with a `vip BOOLEAN` column and add foreign key in `persons` table. Make the following changes in the schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `organisations` (
    organisation_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(64),
    vip BOOLEAN,
    PRIMARY KEY (organisation_id)
);

INSERT INTO `organisations` (name, vip) VALUES
    ("VIP-org", True),
    ("VIP inc.", True),
    ("Evil Corp", False),
    ("Rome", False);

CREATE TABLE persons (
    person_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(64),
    organisation_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (organisation_id) REFERENCES `organisations`(organisation_id) 
);

INSERT INTO `persons` (name, organisation_id) VALUES
    ("Guy Fieri", 1),
    ("Fiona", 2),
    ("Mr. Robot", 3),
    ("Marcus Antonius", 4),
    ("Cicero", 4),
    ("Shrek", 2);
```

Now the query would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT `organisations`.name as organisation, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM `presentations`
JOIN `persons` ON `presentations`.person_id = `persons`.person_id
JOIN `organisations` ON `organisations`.organisation_id = `persons`.organisation_id
GROUP BY `organisations`.organisation_id
ORDER BY `organisations`.vip DESC, count DESC;
```

Output:

```
+--------------+------------+
| organisation |      count |
+--------------+------------+
| VIP inc.     |          5 |
| VIP-org      |          4 |
| Rome         |          7 |
| Evil Corp    |          5 |
+--------------+------------+
```

You can see the result here: [db <> fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7a8aec2a398c204d548bd6d0086f065a)

Comment: Thank you for the in depth answer! Although I would have preferred to do it like this as well, I have to work with what I have: which is a non-trivial amount of data in the format I specified. If there's ever a good opportunity to convert the tables in-place I will do so.

Comment: @USB_S0lderer I understand your point. If you can't update the schema because of the data then you would have to do it like how you did it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grouping by, I needed to sort. DOh!

Edit: this doesn't quite work. It does not sort by count. If I put the `ORDER BY count` clause first, it puts all vip orgs on the bottom.

Edit 2: using `EXISTS`, it seems to work

```
SELECT organisation, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM `presentations`
JOIN `persons` ON `presentations`.person_id = `persons`.person_id
GROUP BY organisation
ORDER BY EXISTS (SELECT org_name FROM `VIP_orgs` WHERE `VIP_orgs`.org_name = organisation) DESC, count DESC;
```

Comment: Instead of grouping by, I needed to sort - so why is there still a group by in your solution?

Comment: @P.Salmon the first group is to make sure all persons get grouped by organisation, so that the amount of presentations of the organisation, not of the individual, get counted.

Comment: Typically, the PK in one table is the FK in another; this is an essential requirement of data integrity.

Comment: Another design might be a table of organisations, with a column to identify those that are 'VIP'

Comment: @Strawberry exactly this is what I suggested in the comment of the question.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz I agree. Boss wanted me to do it like this.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz What can I say? Great minds think alike.